# Translate "collective unconscious" into Latin

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

I would like to translate the phrase "collective unconscious" [coined by Carl Jung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_unconscious), into classical Latin. It does not need to be a literal translation as long as it conveys the same concept of a shared unconscious between all members of a species.

For context, I've been working on creating a mythology (long term pet project) and Latin is used as a "high speech" in the way that Stephen King has [High and Low Speech](https://www.stephenking.com/darktower/glossary.html) in his dark tower novels (which I imagine was inspired by the Romans and vulgar vs classical Latin).

Comment: A possible lead: I believe Carl Jung knew Latin, so possibly he coined a Latin phrase for this himself. I don't know where to begin looking to see if he did, though.

Comment: I tried Googling and couldn't really find anything. Did the Romans have the concept of the unconscious in the way that we do?

Comment: They have words for simply being _not conscious_, but I don't know if they had the concept of thought as being conscious and unconscious.

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t an answer but (frequent excuse) it’s too long for a comment.

One of the key indigestibilities of Aristotle, when we were absorbing him in the c13, was *precisely* the question of the collective versus the individual *intellectual* soul. The Muslim commentators seemed to be happy with the idea of “the mind of Man” as opposed to the mind of *each* man; Christians clearly were not. It took Aquinas to disentangle the problem.

In the course of this disentanglement a vocabulary will have been developed to talk about the distinction in Latin, and this with a small amount of realignment will probably give the most natural step towards “Jungius”.

You can tell I’m away from my books! But if you are interested enough to see how *essentially the same questions as Jung’s* were being handled by the mediaeval renaissance, possible ways in might be Pieper’s *Introduction to Aquinas* or either Copleston’s *History of Mediaeval Philosophy* or the relevant volume of his overall *History of Philosophy*. Thus equipped, you will be in a position to see where in Aquinas to look in order to check the precise technical vocabulary he is using.

Comment: Looking forward to know the terms used!

Comment: I did a little digging based on your comment, and one possible phrase that Aquinas may have meant for it is "Unitate Intellectus", or "Unity of Intellect". They mention it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averroes%27_theory_of_the_unity_of_the_intellect